# How to clone an icon

Tags: windows, winapi, icons, gdi

In Windows, given a handle to an icon (`HICON`), how do you clone it?

e.g.

```
HICON CloneIcon(HICON OriginalIcon)
{
    ICON clone;
    //...

    return clone;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Win32 API function [`DuplicateIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648066.aspx):

```
HICON CloneIcon(HICON OriginalIcon)
{
    return DuplicateIcon(NULL, OriginalIcon); //first parameter is unused
}
```

Comment: For reference, there's also CopyIcon, why does the same thing: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131004-00/?p=3033

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Delphi code to clone an icon.

```
function CloneIcon(ico: HICON): HICON;
var
    info: ICONINFO;
    bm: BITMAP;
    cx, cy: Integer;
begin
   //Get the icon's info (e.g. its bitmap)
   GetIconInfo(ico, {var}info);

   //Get the bitmap info associated with the icon's color bitmap
   GetObject(info.hbmColor, sizeof(bm), @bm);

   //Copy the actual icon, now that we know its width and height
   Result := CopyImage(ico, IMAGE_ICON, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, 0);

   DeleteObject(info.hbmColor);
   DeleteObject(info.hbmMask);
end;
```

And transcoding to a C/C#-style language in my head:

```
HICON CloneIcon(HICON ico)
{
   ICONINFO info;

   //Get the icon's info (e.g. its bitmap)
   GetIconInfo(ico, ref info);

   //Get the bitmap info associated with the icon's color bitmap    
   BITMAP bm;
   GetObject(info.hbmColor, sizeof(bm), &bm));

   //Copy the actual icon, now that we know its width and height
   HICON result = CopyImage(ico, IMAGE_ICON, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, 0);

   DeleteObject(info.hbmColor);
   DeleteObject(info.hbmMask);

   return result;
}
```

> **Note**: Any code released into public domain. No attribution required.

Comment: Not only is this somewhat needless, it also leaks the two bitmaps returned in the `ICONINFO` struct.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The code, basically, comes out of .NET `Icon.Clone`; yes they get `GetIconInfo`, `GetObject`, and `CopyImage`. The .NET FCL does have a call to `DeleteSomething` in there. My translation was to get something done while i wait for a real answer.